# Gmap.NET drawing routes with spikes on certain zoom levels

Tags: c#, drawing, gmap.net

I'm using the Gmap.NET control to draw routes on maps which works basically fine, but on certain zoom levels it creates those "spikes" on some tour stations. Especially when the way to the station is the same as when leaving it again.

Example with a spike (station 3):

[image: spike on station 3]

Correct plotting of the route when zooming one level further down:

[image: no spike on this zoom level]

I hope the problem is clear.

Any ideas what this is and how to handle it?

Edit: This is one of the routes creating the issue. stations:

```
0 = 53.42853, 9.94964
1 = 53.4234, 10.0205 
2 = 53.36294, 9.98961
3 = 53.22015, 10.17786
4 = 53.23748, 10.15987
5 = 53.42853, 9.94964
```

And the whole routing: https://nopaste.xyz/?272dc860d24033de#GqwkHCVP88IB/SdXzJFzTCSJqjfdM7cX20/qoyCOVbY=

Thank you,
Michel.

Comment: Can you provide a route that creates this issue?

Comment: @gunnerone, I've added the stations and the pointlist of the route.

Comment: Here's what I get: https://pasteboard.co/HwS4GcY.png  Does this show the issue?  Do I need to be at a specific zoom?

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't because you are just _beelining_ the stations of the route. Please see the whole point list I have attached via the nopast.xyz link.

Comment: I'm having a hard time identifying the "spikes" at any zoom level.  Here's what I get with all of the points: https://pasteboard.co/Hx0ILNR.png  https://pasteboard.co/Hx0KsTe.png

Comment: Also what version of Gmap are you using?

Comment: I got v1.7.5 of both GMap.NET.Core and GMap.NET.WindowsForms. I tentatively reduced the line width to 2px. Helps a little, but problem still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to load your route coordinates and test them on the map and i didn't see the problem exactly.

[image: ALL 809 Route points loaded][image]

While searching, i found an answer for your prolem in this link [How can I get rid of these 'spike' visual artifacts when drawing with WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12931566/2813117), the question was for the WPF version but you will get the idea.

in short, the problem was in the Route **Line Joins Type** (**Miter, Bevel, Round**) like in this image:
[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I lost track of the issue. But this is the correct answer. Very helpful, thanks a ton.